# Is there a general term for small objects used in sewing/tailoring/knitting etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

Needles, thimbles, hooks and so on. I feel like there should be some all-encompassing word for that but I can't find it.

Comment: I've got this **notion** that there's a term...  Now what was it??

Comment: _Notions_ is a term that has been in use, though it's a bit old-fashioned. The OED says it means 'Small wares, esp. cheap useful articles of some ingenious design. Now spec. in haberdashery.'

Comment: I think of notions as more the stuff you sew into things. Like a zipper.

Comment: I feel like we ought to be _findings_ an answer.

Comment: A [ditty bag](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ditty-bag) has all those things in it, or used to. *Kit* would work also.

Comment: I think fabric stores still would have a notions section.